# Firebase Realtime on iOS: Cannot access Realtime Database

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting the following error:

> [Firebase/Database][I-RDB034005] Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server.  Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Firebase error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly

Permissions on admin console are set .read and .write to false

I understand the error. when I run the following command and print the value of variable:

```
Database.database().reference()
```

I get (cant edit it):

https://bananas-31fe5-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com

And on admin console I have (cant edit it):

https://bananas-31fe5-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app

On admin console, I tried creating a new database (and disabling the primary one) on the US, but   the one on xcode doesnt seem to change.

My gut feeling is this has to do with the pod library not being updated to enable multiple db location (EU is in beta).

Comment: I received this error because I clicked the wrong button on the left in the firebase console and created a Firestore Database instead of a Realtime Database. Once I created the correct database the error resolved and the app works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*firebaser here*

For non-US-central databases the SDK may not be able to read the information from the `plist` file, so you have to pass it in the code.

You can pass the database URL into the call to `database`, like:

```
Database.database("https://bananas-31fe5-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app").reference()
```

See [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/Database#databaseurl:) for that method override.

Comment: The app crashes: 'Invalid URL (https://bananas-31fe5-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app) passed to getReference(). URL was expected to match configured Database URL: https://bananas-31fe5-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com'

Comment: Hmmm... that should work from what I understand. Can you put the exact code that you use in your question? Also: what version of the iOS SDK are you using?

Comment: A team mate spotted my mistake: the database URL needs to go into the call to `database(...)`. I fixed it in my answer too, so give it a spin.

Answer (score 4):

When you create a realtime database for the first time, DATABASE_URL is added to your GoogleService-Info.plist file on the server side. You may be getting an error because the GoogleService-Info.plist is outdated and does not contain DATABASE_URL. You can download your updated GoogleService-Info.plist file from your Project Settings and try again.

I hope it helped